# Errors in RSpec test when using attributes_for with my factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I've got the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    name "Example  category"
    user_id 1
  end
end
```

This is my test:

```
describe "POST #create" do
  context "signed in" do
    before(:each) do
      sign_in :user, user
    end

    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "saves the new category in the database" do
        expect{
          post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:category)
        }.to change(Category, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "redirects to category #index"
    end

    context "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not save the new category in the database"
      it "re-renders the :new template"
      it "provides errors"
    end
  end

  context "not signed in" do
    it "blocks access (somehow)"
  end
end
```

But, I'm getting the following error when I run my test:

```
3) CategoriesController POST #create signed in with valid attributes saves the new category in the database
  Failure/Error: post :create, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:category)
  ActionController::ParameterMissing:
    param not found: category
```

I've managed to use the factory previously, it works fine in my spec/model/ tests. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I can't see any problem with the factory. I'm a little lost :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the key:

```
post :create, category: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:category)
```